# I got a different result when I retrained the sentiment model with Stanford CoreNLP to compare with the related paper's result

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I downloaded  stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09.
And I created a training model with the following command:

```
 java -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25 -trainPath train.txt -devPath dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz
```

When I finished training, I found many files in my directory.
[the model list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2fSc.jpg)

Then I used the evaluation tool from the package and I ran the code like this:

```
java -cp * edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.Evaluate -model model-0024-79.82.ser.gz -treebank test.txt
```

The test.txt was from trainDevTestTrees_PTB.zip. This is the result about code:

```
F:\trainDevTestTrees_PTB\trees>java -cp * edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.Evaluate -model model-0024-79.82.ser.gz -treebank test.txt
EVALUATION SUMMARY
Tested 82600 labels
65331 correct
17269 incorrect
0.790932 accuracy
Tested 2210 roots
890 correct
1320 incorrect
0.402715 accuracy
Label confusion matrix
  Guess/Gold       0       1       2       3       4    Marg. (Guess)
           0     551     340      87      32       6    1016
           1     956    5348    2476     686     191    9657
           2     354    2812   51386    3097     467   58116
           3     146     744    2525    6804    1885   12104
           4       1      11      74     379    1242    1707
Marg. (Gold)    2008    9255   56548   10998    3791

           0        prec=0.54232, recall=0.2744, spec=0.99423, f1=0.36442
           1        prec=0.5538, recall=0.57785, spec=0.94125, f1=0.56557
           2        prec=0.8842, recall=0.90871, spec=0.74167, f1=0.89629
           3        prec=0.56213, recall=0.61866, spec=0.92598, f1=0.58904
           4        prec=0.72759, recall=0.32762, spec=0.9941, f1=0.4518

Root label confusion matrix
  Guess/Gold       0       1       2       3       4    Marg. (Guess)
           0      50      60      12       9       3     134
           1     161     370     147      94      36     808
           2      31     103     102      60      32     328
           3      36      97     123     305     265     826
           4       1       3       5      42      63     114
Marg. (Gold)     279     633     389     510     399

           0        prec=0.37313, recall=0.17921, spec=0.9565, f1=0.24213
           1        prec=0.45792, recall=0.58452, spec=0.72226, f1=0.51353
           2        prec=0.31098, recall=0.26221, spec=0.87589, f1=0.28452
           3        prec=0.36925, recall=0.59804, spec=0.69353, f1=0.45659
           4        prec=0.55263, recall=0.15789, spec=0.97184, f1=0.24561

Approximate Negative label accuracy: 0.638817
Approximate Positive label accuracy: 0.697140
Combined approximate label accuracy: 0.671925
Approximate Negative root label accuracy: 0.702851
Approximate Positive root label accuracy: 0.742574
Combined approximate root label accuracy: 0.722680
```

The accuracy about fine-grained and positive/negative was quite different from the paper "Socher, R., Perelygin, A., Wu, J.Y., Chuang, J., Manning, C.D., Ng, A.Y. and Potts, C., 2013, October. Recursive deep models for semantic compositionality over a sentiment treebank. In Proceedings of the conference on empirical methods in natural language processing (EMNLP) (Vol. 1631, p. 1642)." 
The paper states the accuracy about fine-grained and positive/negative is higher than mine.
[The records in the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdQ84.jpg)

Were there any problems with my operation? Why was my result different from the paper?

Comment: This is probably better directed at the paper's authors.

Comment: I'll ask around and see if I can get some more details for you!

Comment: Have you been able to get better results? I was really wondering because in the paper he references to the java code.

Comment: Sorry about it. I have not got better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the paper used a different system written in Matlab.  The Java system does not match the paper.  Though we do distribute the binary model we trained in Matlab with the English models jar.  So you can RUN the binary model with Stanford CoreNLP, but you cannot TRAIN a binary model with similar performance with Stanford CoreNLP at this time.

Comment: How did you trained the models **(sentiment.ser.gz and sentiment.binary.ser.gz)** which you provide in the **stanford-english-corenlp-2016-01-10-models.jar**? Because I was able to reproduce with theses models the the same results like in the paper **http://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/EMNLP2013_RNTN.pdf**. The models work with the java implementation. Therefore, I think you also trained these models with java implementation? I try to reproduce the results for my master thesis therefore I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: The binary model was trained with our Matlab system.  We have not been able to produce a similar model with our Java system.  So you cannot train with the Java system and produce that binary model.  But we distribute the binary model.  So to be clear, you can run the binary model we produced with the Matlab system with the Java system, but you cannot load in training data and train a binary model with similar performance with the Java system.

Comment: So in short, the best model we trained with our Matlab system outperforms the best model we trained with our Java system.  It is unclear why this is at this time...

Comment: But we can convert the system built in Matlab into a format that the Java system can use.  So that is why you see the same performance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it also possible to get the matlab code? In theory the java implementation should be the same like the matlab code?

Comment: Can you tell me the best results you achieved with the java implementation for the fine-grained results and the parameters you used because I was not able find better ones than the standard parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this information.  I see you are talking to John on an email thread about this.  I would recommend we wait for his reply this week.  If you still have questions I can continue to ask around, but a lot of (all of?) the people who worked on that system have graduated and left the group!

Comment: One thing I should add is it's definitely important to train the binary model as a binary model (rather than train a 5-class model and then infer binary decisions).